# Requirements of a random variable X

Tags: statistics, random-variables

If I have an experiment where you throw a 6 sided die, and also toss a coin, and I wanted to represent this experiment with a random variable $X$ which **completely** characterizes the experiment, what are the requirements of this random variable?

Does it Have to have the same sample space as the experiment? Can it be a many-to-one mapping of the experiment sample space to the real numbers?

What if I just say, no matter what value the die gives, it is worth "1" and the coin toss is also worth 0 or 1 depending on whether its **Tails** or **Heads**? Is that valid?

Or what if, no matter, the value of X is always 1?

Comment: I never formally studied Probablity Theory.  However, my intuition indicates that the purpose behind a random variable is to distinguish the occurrence of various possible events.  If the random variable is assigned the same value, regardless of what value is given by the die, then you can not use the random variable to distinguish between the various events of the die showing different values.

Comment: A random variable is a (measurable) function from the sample space to the real numbers. For many purposes, we are not interested in the actual sample space it is defined on, but rather its distribution. In other words, the sample space is just an abstract object. The real object of interest is the distribution function $t\mapsto P(X\leq t)$

Comment: @AndrewZhang So are you implying that we can have a random variable X that is not a one to one mapping of the sample space to the real numbers, and it still represents the experiment completely? Since that is the question...

Comment: I don't really understand your question / the motivation. I think you are being too vague with what you are asking. 

For example, the sample mean and variance are sufficient for a normal distribution, and there are many sufficient statistics, which are not injective (if they were, then no data reduction would be achieved!) Does a sufficient statistic represent the experiment completely? That of course depends what represents the experiment completely means.

Comment: If you have two experiments then why not use two random variables. i.e. a random vector to represent it ? . That is let $X$ take values $1,2,3,4,5,6$ and $Y$ take values $0,1$ . Then on the lattice, you have your representation. As Andre said , the sample space is not very important. For all practical purposes, you only need $[0,1]$ and products of $[0,1]$ as your sample space to do most of probability theory. But all of these requires the notion of Measure theory and Product measure(to characterize indepdendence) .

Comment: So for an elementary treatment, why not consider $X$ and $Y$ as I suggested and then you specify the joint distribution. i.e. the values of $P(X=i,Y=j)$ accordingly . That would describe your entire experiment. To do it rigorously , you will also need to define the mapping $X:[0,1]\to \{1,2,...,6\}$ and also $Y$ . That is involve the sample space. That can be done by simply taking $X=\sum_{i=1}^{6}i\cdot\mathbf{1}_{[\frac{i-1}{6},\frac{i}{6})}$ and $Y=\mathbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$ . So $(X,Y)$ will now be defined on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron this question is not about simple mappings that we all know are valid, it is about mappings like saying X and Y where X is 0 or 1, and Y is even or odd. Does that completely characterize the experiment?

Comment: @AndrewZhang this is precisely my problem. My lecturer has given this question and I also find it to be too vague, what does "completely characterize" mean? That's why I posted this question

Comment: @ripbozo Well if you ponder for a moment on the comments of Andrew and me, then you will find that again and again we emphasize that the mapping itself is unimportant and sometimes even fruitless to think about. What matters is the **distribution**. What your instructor most likely wants is the scenario I described where you make the random vector $(X,Y)$ take values in $(i,j):  i\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \,, j\in\{0,1\}$ . and then you specify the Probabilities $P(X=i,Y=j)$ . This is called specifying the joint distribution which completely characterizes the distribution of the random vector $(X,Y)$

Comment: A special case of the experiment is when the toss and the dice throws are indpendendent. Then $P(X=i,Y=j)=\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$ . This in particular will be a good enough representation for your experiment(s) in the independent case. However, they need not be indpendent , and to cover for such scenarios , you would need to specify individually what $P(X=i,Y=j)$ are. For example, consider that if head falls then the die can only given even values or some other dependence which may be even more complicated.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I understand, but my lecturer expects me to judge the validity of a provided sample variable such that X and Y where X is 0 or 1, and Y is even or odd. I understand that is a valid distribution, and based on your comment now then it does not matter about the mapping and it should be valid?

Comment: Definition: A random variable is a function which maps the sample space to a real number. It assigns a real number to each simple event.
SO in theory I can assign all of the sample space to One real number, and call it a day, since the question does not ask for any specific distribution.
That is why I am so confused about what is valid and what is not

Comment: Your dice throw and coin toss could have $6 \times 2=12$ potential joint outcomes, so I would have thought you are being asked for a random variable with support on $12$ values with each value corresponding to a different joint outcome

Comment: @Henry according to Mr.GandalfSauron and AndrewZhang, the mapping should not really matter...

Comment: Some non-1-1 mappings lose information and so do not "completely characterize the experiment"